# Почему не срабатывает декодер логов в OSSEC Astra Linux 1.5 и сообщения не появляются?

Tags: linux, debian, безопасность, логирование, astra-linux

Настраиваю OSSEC в Астре Смоленск.
На серваке логи с клиента сыпятся в **/var/remote_logs//all.log**. 
На сколько я понимаю, **all.log** должен парсится ossec'ом в реалтайме и верно декодированые сообщения по заданным правилам падают в **/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.log**. Но такого не происходит. 
Команда

```
cat /var/remote_logs/<ip-client>/all.log | tail -n 1  | ./ossec-logtest
```

выдала, откуда следует, что декодеры верно настроены.

```
**Phase 1: Completed pre-decoding.
       full event: 'May 23 18:37:10 client parselog: [p] 'Wed May 23 18:25:45 2018' '/usr/bin/parselog' <25621,25290,0,0,0> [s] open("/etc/parsec/mlog/events_user.conf",O_RDONLY) = 13'
       hostname: 'client'
       program_name: 'parselog'
       log: '[p] 'Wed May 23 18:25:45 2018' '/usr/bin/parselog' <25621,25290,0,0,0> [s] open("/etc/parsec/mlog/events_user.conf",O_RDONLY) = 13'

**Phase 2: Completed decoding.
       decoder: 'parselog-p-s'

**Phase 3: Completed filtering (rules).
       Rule id: '130004'
       Level: '5'
       Description: 'Открытие файла'
**Alert to be generated.
```

./list_agents -c показывает, что агент доступен.
Где я что не понимаю? Или забыл? Или еще что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать файл `/var/ossec/active-response/bin/reboot.sh` с содержимим

```
#!/bin/bash

RS_TMP="/var/ossec/tmp/.restarting"
AR_LOG="/var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log"

if [[ -f $RS_TMP ]]
then
        rm $RS_TMP
        echo "`date` Restart done"  >> $AR_LOG
else
        touch $RS_TMP
        /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control restart
        echo "`date` Restart begin..." >> $AR_LOG
fi
```

и назначить права

```
chmod 550 /var/ossec/active-response/bin/reboot.sh
chown root.ossec /var/ossec/active-response/bin/reboot.sh
```

Теперь в конфиге `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf` создаём запись команды:

```
<command>
  <name>reboot-restart</name>
  <executable>reboot.sh</executable>
  <expect></expect>
</command>
```

и триггер, на который она срабатывает. Это правило **502** - запуск `ossec`, единственное, что падает в `alerts.log`:

```
  <active-response>
    <command>reboot-restart</command>
    <location>server</location>
    <rules_id>502</rules_id>
  </active-response>
```

Перезагружаем, радуемся.